# Understanding forEach in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to understand/comprehend `.forEach` loop in Javascript.

Now, I get it simply

```js
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4] 

numberArray.forEach(x => {
console.log(x) 
})
```

As expected it would return output

```
1
2
3
4
```

Now, Since forEach is a function, I decided to return something and store its value

```js
 let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4] 

let newNum = numberArray.forEach(x => x) 

console.log(newNum)
```

This is returning `undefined` when I am clearly returning something and it again it is a function.

Can someone tell me what am I missing here? I mean I the background of forEach loop

**[Update:]** I know many other ways to achieve my goal, I am more interested to know more about this behaviour for `forEach`

Comment: That the job of `map` not `forEach`: [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @soktinpk I know about the map but was just messing around and evaluating result of JS

Comment: `.forEach` doesn't use return values, or return anything itself.   That's what `.map` is for.

Comment: `forEach` is a `Function` returning `void 0` (or `undefined`, really). It acts on the `array`, returning **nothing**. You probably wanted `map` instead. If you're familiar with any other **non weak-typed language** it's a `void` function/method, so you're trying to log the result of a `void` function.

Comment: Do you want `newNum` to be the sum of the numbers in the array? If so then take a look at: [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#forEach` does not return anything, it makes an operation on every element in a specified array then returns `undefined`.

You are probably looking for `Array#map` which as well as `Array#forEach` makes an operation on every element in some array then returns the result as a new array.

```js
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let newNum = numberArray.map(x => x);

console.log(newNum);
```

*"As expected it would return output"* - no, it was not returned. It was logged into console by `console.log` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If you can answer following as well `forEach` takes a callback and I am returning something in that callback.

Comment: @VarunBindal It's not returning anything. And even if you do, and return something, it won't be included in the result, it will still return `undefined`. `Array#forEach` was meant to iterate over an array and make some external or mutating operation. It will modify existing array. It won't return a new one. You can read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @VarunBindal the `forEach` argument (the callback) is (like the `forEach` method itself) a `void` function, meaning that its result is **unused** in the `forEach` prototype code. In a nutshell, returning `x` or not returning anything in the foreach callback will equally act on it. That method was meant to iterate by **reference** (if you're not working with an array of primitives like you are) the original array, **altering it** but **without** returning a new one.

Comment: @briosheje This is what I was exactly looking for. 
The understanding of `forEach` rather got lot of answers/comments suggesting alternative. 
Still glad that people answered and contributed in their own way.

Comment: @VarunBindal then the best you can (always) do for educational purposes is to take the official MDN link (as provied by kind user above), navigate to the "polyfill" section and see the polyfill implementation, here is the direct link to the div: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill . As you can see, you can find the whole implementation of it, this should help you to properly understand what happens behind `forEach`. To answer to your question, read point 8 ("return undefined")

Answer (score 1):

This case you will get the same array back with the forEach:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  array.forEach(i => {
    i => i;
  });

  console.log(array);
```

Note that you will use .forEach() to iterate on collections and .map() to actually create a new array.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, another example:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var myNumber = 1;

  array.forEach(i => {
    myNumber = i;
  });

  console.log(myNumber); // 4
```

Here, every iteration the variable myNumber value will change to the value of i. On the end of the iterations the value of myNumber will be the value of the last element of the array. Hope it helps!

Comment: What is `i => i;` supposed to be? It just declares an anonymous arrow function and discard it immediately, for each item in the array.

Comment: Agree that it is pretty useless. But OP's question was about that. Nonetheless I already point that use map to create a new array, and use .forEach to only iterate an existing one.

Comment: If you log `array` already you don't even need to put the `foreach` at all. I would suggest you to resee / test your code, since the addition you provided currently does nothing neither to make forEach more understandable, nor to provide a working example.

Comment: frankly, I think doing `i => i;` is useless here and not even relevant but thanks for answering though. 

I am not the one to downvote your answer here :)

Comment: I agree with you, it is pretty useless, I updated my post to explain forEach more.

Comment: Upvoting partially because whoever downvoted this is not really thinking objectively in terms of useful answers. That and I think this actually better explains what `#forEach` does than the accepted answer which focuses on `#map`

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson The answer is edited. Previously the answer was sort of vague, The marked answer have a better explanation in the comment. Upvoted this answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

forEach doesn't return anything. It uses each value in the array as a first argument to call the function you're providing.